# How to play locally stored videos with html5 player

Tags: html

I am having issues getting locally stored videos to play on HTML5 player. I've checked the path and it seems to be correct and the file I can confirm is there but the video just won't play anything.

```
<video width="640" height="264" controls>
    <source src= 'big_buck_bunny.mp4' type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: In which browser and is any console error or warning

Comment: Both the latest versions of chrome and safari and no console errors or warnings. It just when I press play nothing starts. I tried with an external link to a video and it works for

Answer (score 0):

I had to move my video files to public